# Failed to make requests to ESP8266 Webserver from an android app

Tags: arduino, webserver, esp8266, nodemcu, mdns

So I have an ESP device that is connected to my WiFi network. It runs a web server and now I want to make requests to this webserver from my android app. So I tried a couple of things and none got satisfied.

Things I tried and why not suitable for me.

---

**Setting up mDNS:**
Can't use it since android doesn't really do mDNS it fails in the lookup.

**Setting a Static IP:**
This approach will fail if the routers' gateway is changed. (at least that's what I believe).
(Can anyone elaborate on this ^. AFAIK if you want to make a static IP you need to match the given gateway with your router's gateway, So if I configured esp board for my router, it might not work with someone else's router.)

**Setting a WebSocket connection:**
To do this also need the hostname which is IP again.

**Asking IP from user:** 
Since this is going to be a product I can't ask the user to provide the IP address in the mobile application. It leads to a lack of user experience.

---

I still hope that there should be another way of handling this case which I'm not aware of. I'm actually dying to get this done and I need you guys to help me with this.

Comment: Since this is going t be a product maybe you should hire a consultant who understands networking.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80768/set-parameters-after-compilation/80773#80773) on Arduino will help.

Comment: I think I can get this done using both ap mode and sta mode together. I will try to come up with a solution. There should be a better way of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are over complicating stuff here.

Step 1. Connect esp board to your wifi (i guess you have figured this out)
step 2. check what lan address your board has connected to, for this is usually just use

```
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
```

step 3. start your wifiserver at port 80

```
WiFiServer(80);
```

step 4. in your android app, or any other platform(i recommend using browser in computer while simply testing if it works or not) type url: local_ip_address_that_you_got_above/mygetrequest?value1=1

step 5. Listen for incoming clients and intercept the get value that you will recieve in the header in fashion of "GET /mygetrequest?value1=1"

step 6. done :)

If you want to skip the process of implementing all of it from scratch you can get full source code of my example server described above at: https://spacerival.com/lounge/2614/arduino-server but i do highly suggest you to implement it on your own and not just copy paste that source code, since you wont learn much at all to be fair

Comment: this is going to be a consumer product that doesn't have any serial monitors to print anything! A product which is standalone like "mood lamp".

Comment: That would not matter in this case, the serial monitors are used in the debugging phase only, once you upload your code to the esp board, you will not be seeing that serial monitor logs anyways. I would personally always recommend to use one esp board for just debugging, and then when you feel the code is ok, save all of the code, and upload that code to all production esp boards

Comment: @CharithaGoonewardena incase you mean that the consumer of your product wont be able to know what their local ip address is, that is always going to be their responsibility, you simply need to accept that.

So you really only have a single option, you will create a website, and your esp board will only communicate with your website. The android app will only communicate with your website. your WEBSITE then will handle the controlling of the esp board, then the user will never need to configure anything or need any local ip address at all

Comment: Since the website is a static ip address that never changes, you can preconfigure to set android app to send a GET message like this www.example.com/?myprivateespboard1=id&turnlampon=true, in your website you would store this request. Then in the esp board, every 30 seconds you could simply fetch data from your website to check if any commands has been sent... sadly there is no other way to do it if you want customer to have a good experience. My personal choice would be to use local ip addresses, let the customer figure out his local ip, and type it once in your android application, perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but it is more like a workaround. There should be some other way to handle this. I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying all day long, I came with a solution. This is a bit of a workaround as I was lost. So What I did was I created a Soft AP with a small web server that returns the LocalIP. So my esp is working on both AP and STA modes right now.

How it works is simple

1. ESP runs with a small webserver with `/getLocalIP` endpoint.
2. ESP opens a SoftAP for the user to connect. The user connects with the
   SoftAP.
3. The user will be asked to enter credentials for the desired
   WiFi.
4. After connecting to the desired WiFi mobile app will request a
   for `192.168.4.1/getLocalIP` (AP's IP Address).
5. Since ESP is already connected to the WiFi this endpoint will send the `WiFi.localIP()` to the app.
6. So now the app has the LocalIP.

Comment: Another solution would be to have a WebSocket connection with the mobile client. So it will be having the connection between SoftAP IP and Mobile app.